# Is there an object like a "Set" that can contain only unique string values, but also contain a count on the number of occurrences of the string value?

Tags: java, data-structures

In Java is there an object like a "Set" that can contain only unique string values, but also contain a count on the number of occurrences of the string value?

The idea is simple

With a data set ala...

A
B
B
C
C
C

I'd like to add each line of text to a Set-like object.  Each time that a non-unique text is added to the set I'd like to also have a numeric value associated with the set to display how many times it was added.  So if I ran it on the above data set the output would be something like:

A : 1
B : 2
C : 3

any ideas?

Comment: If it contains "only unique string values" then the count will always be 1 for every string it contains.

Comment: Yes, this data set has multiple non-unique string values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Map<String, Integer>` would be the best bet, to put in words what you want to do is to *Map the amount of occurrences of a string*. Basically have something like this:

```
public void add(String s) {
    if (map.containsKey(s)) {
        map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(s, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. I've used Maps for this sort of thing countless times. I think it's the best solution--it doesn't involve much work on your part. The only issue is that retrieving things from the map and dealing with Java's clunky Map.Entry is annoying.

Comment: Thanks - I also wound up changing it into a hashmap

Comment: I wouldn't call Map.Entry clunky, however admittedly it has its oddities such as the capability of getting garbage collected almost immediately which may result in Heisenbugs in single-threaded programs.

Comment: If you use this approach frequently, consider using Google's Multiset.  Or write your own Bag<T> wrapper class with an API similar to Multiset's and implemented using a Map<T, Integer>.

Answer (score 16):

You want a "Bag", like the [Bag](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html) in Apache Commons Collections or the [Multiset](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) in Google Collections.  You can add the same value to it multiple times, and it'll record the counts of each value.  You can then interrogate the counts.

You'd do something like this with Apache Commons' [Bag](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html):

```
Bag myBag = new HashBag();
myBag.add("Orange");
myBag.add("Apple", 4);
myBag.add("Apple");
myBag.remove("Apple", 2);
int apples = myBag.getCount("Apple");  // Should be 3.
int kumquats = myBag.getCount("Kumquat"); // Should be 0.
```

And this with Google Collections' [Multiset](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

```
Multiset<String> myMultiset= HashMultiset.create();
myMultiset.add("Orange");
myMultiset.add("Apple", 4);
myMultiset.add("Apple");
myMultiset.remove("Apple", 2);
int apples = myMultiset.count("Apple");  // 3
int kumquats = myMultiset.count("Kumquats");  // 0
```

The problem with Apache Collections in general is that it isn't being very actively maintained, and it doesn't yet support Java Generics.  To step into this gap, Google's written their own [Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) which are extremely powerful.  Be sure to evaluate Google Collections first.

Update: Google Collections also offers Multimap, a "collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values with a single key".

Comment: Which fully implements the map<X, Integer> as described in other responses

Comment: Why even mention `Bag` and Apache Collections? Google Collections in general and its `Multiset` in particular is better in every respect.

Comment: Completely agree! I looked at Google first for Bag, forgetting that it was called a Multiset.

Comment: Okay! If you aren't really a Commons fanatic then you get +1 from me.

Comment: @sylvarking: I've updated the entry to show both and recommend Google first.  (StackOverflow rewards quick incomplete answers over more thoughtful ones, so it seems best to answer quickly and then make sure it's right/complete.)

Comment: Someone who can edit -- in place of <code>Multisets.newHashMultiset</code> it should be <code>HashMultiset.create</code>.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks, I corrected the example, which was adapted from an article that must have been using an earlier version.

Answer (score 2):

Yeap, not directly in the core, but can be built easily with  a [Map](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Here's a naive implementation:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SetLike {
    private Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    public void add( String s ) {
        if( !map.containsKey( s ) ){
            map.put( s, 0 );
        }
        map.put( s, map.get( s ) + 1 );
    }

    public void printValuesAndCounts() {
        System.out.println( map );
    }

    public static void main( String [] args ){
        String [] data = {"A","B","B","C","C","C"};

        SetLike holder = new SetLike();

        for( String value : data ) {
            holder.add( value );
        }

        holder.printValuesAndCounts();
    }
}
```

Test it

```
$ javac SetLike.java 
$ java SetLike
{A=1, C=3, B=2}
```

Of course you can improve it much more. You can implement the Set interface, or a List, or a Collection, etc, you can add the iterators, implement Iterable and so on, it depends on what you want and what you need.

Comment: How would I use a map to get the results above?

Comment: @inSqlHell: I have posted the code. I didn't want to post the idea I've got until I see it running ;)

Comment: I really liked this: `System.out.println( map );`. I didn't know that. I always make a loop over the hashmap via entryset or keyset to print the values! Thanks! +1 :)

Comment: BTW, I didn't get this: "You can implement the Set interface, or ...". As far as I know, set (and hash set) does not support duplicates, how can we use them to count frequencies? Maybe you mean we should use `if(!hashset.add(s)){ count++; }`, right? (and count should be initialized 1)

Comment: @Hengameh well yes, that and implement the rest of the interface ( for instance did you noticed my add method return type is void instead of boolean? )  Support generics, etc. etc. this was just a quick simple example to show it can be easily done.

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful..

```
    List<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add("A");
    myList.add("B");
    myList.add("B");
    myList.add("C");
    myList.add("C");
    myList.add("C");        

    Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>(myList);

    for (String value : set)
    {
        int occurance=Collections.frequency(myList, value);
        System.out.println(value +" occur "+occurance + " times ");
    }
```

Result :

```
      A occur 1 times 
      B occur 2 times 
      C occur 3 times
```

Comment: As far as I know, in set or hash set, we cannot add duplicates, since it will overwrite(override). Could you please explain how your method works? (I copied and run it, and it works well! but I cannot understand how!)