# Determine the most common occurrence in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

Assume I have an array of doubles that looks like the following:

```
Array[10] = {10, 10, 10, 3, 10, 10, 6, 10, 10, 9, 10}
```

I need a function that can determine what the MAJORTY vote is in the array, in this case "10" because it is the number that appears the most often...
And of course there is the situation when no majority exists (where they are equal), in that case I need to throw an exception...

Any clues? Aside from doing some really nasty looping on the array (for each index, determine how many exist with the same value, store a count in the array, and then scan the count array for the highest number and the value at that position is the winner, etc...)

Comment: you can do counting sort. and then you find the majority. If the size of the array grows large, counting sort becomes in efficient.

Comment: This sounds like homework, I would be surprised if you need this in a real program. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I need this in a real program. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using a `Map<Integer, Integer>` should be simple as:

```
int mostFrequent(int... ary) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (int a : ary) {
        Integer freq = m.get(a);
        m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
    }

    int max = -1;
    int mostFrequent = -1;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue() > max) {
            mostFrequent = e.getKey();
            max = e.getValue();
        }
    }

    return mostFrequent;
}
```

Comment: There are also the Apache Commons Collections Bag (http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/bag/HashBag.html) and the Google Collections Multiset (http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/package-summary.html) They may be easier or may be overkill, depending on what OP needs it for, but just wanted to mention them.

Answer (score 5):

Your first problem is that you have an "array of doubles", because equality is problematic with floating point data (identical numerical values can be represented by different bit patters, among other things). If your doubles are in fact (as in the example) integers, use `int` instead. Otherweise, think long and hard about how you define what values are equal for the purpose of representing the same vote.

As for determining the majority vote, use a `Map` with the "vote id" as key and the number of votes as value - then in the end iterate through the map to find the maximal value.

Comment: If all the values happen to be integers, then double will work perfectly well. Nor should you be concerned about bit patterns, == will return true iff the values are numerically equal (excluding only NaN). The issue, if any, with double is whether values which are very close should be considered equal. The answer depends on the source of the values (e.g. do they arise from some physical measurement process).

Comment: It all depends on how you arrive at the values you use.  For example, using float to exacerbate the accuracy issues: 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f != 1.0f - 0.1f - 0.1f  Such examples are easy to come by.

Comment: @Mark Thornton, PSpeed is right. Identicality holds only if the floats were instantiated/converted directly, not the result of other float expressions. As such this is a toy example, not real-world, we would need some epsilon for equality comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Sort the array first w/ quick sort and then scan and count for a majority - O(n ln n).  If the range of elements is known ahead of time, say between {1,k}, then a counting sort can be used which will run in O(n+k).

As a slight improvement, as you are scanning the sorted array, if you find value that has more that n/2 occurrences you are done.

Comment: for 10 elements, quick sort would run faster than counting sort :)

Comment: How can we write the code for this solution, which uses 'sorting'? I tried to write, but my code is never terminated. Here's my code: http://ideone.com/eKOWOV

Answer (score 4):

With an array of doubles this might not be easy since equality comparisons on doubles are pretty problematic.
If you can get away with using integers, you can do something like the following:

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int element: Array)
    {
        Integer frequency = map.get(element);
        map.put(element, (frequency != null) ? frequency + 1 : 1);      
    }
    int mostFrequentItem  = 0;
    int[] maxFrequencies  = new int[2];
    maxFrequencies[0]     = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for(Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: map.entrySet())
    {
        if(entry.getValue()>= maxFrequencies[0])
        {
            mostFrequentItem  = entry.getKey();
            maxFrequencies[1] = maxFrequencies[0];
            maxFrequencies[0] = entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    if(maxFrequencies[1] == maxFrequencies[0])
        throw new Exception();//insert whatever exception seems appropriate
            return mostFrequentItem
```

This will have O(n) performance, so it should be pretty optimal in asymptotic performance behaviour. If your doubles are not the results of calculations but come from an other source, that is if you can be sure that values which are basically the same will be represented equally, you might get away with using the same method for doubles, however I would still recommend being careful that this is really the case.

Edit: some performance improvements as suggested in the comment as well as supporting checking for ambiguous case

Comment: +1 for mentioning O(n).  It cannot be faster than that.  A slight improvement can be gained by doing a get instead of a contains as in dfa's response.  But it doesn't affect complexity.

Answer (score 2):

As @Grizzly points out, doubles are problematic from a computational standpoint.  I would also suggest that they don't make sense from the standpoint of your problem domain; doubles don't make any sense with majority voting!

So lets assume that `10` and `6` and so on are integer identifiers for the things people are voting for.  Lets also assume that you know that users can vote any value from `0` to `10`.

```
int[] votes = ...
int[] voteCounts = new int[11];  // 11 could be calculated ...
for (int vote : votes) {
    voteCounts[vote]++;
}
int majority = (votes.length + 1) / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < voteCounts.length; i++) {
    if (voteCounts[i] >= majority) {
        return i;  // the winner!
    }
}
throw new NoClearMajorityException(...);
```

This algorithm is `O(N)` in time and `O(M)` in space, where M is the largest identifier.   The catch is that it only works (as written) if the identifiers are integers.

Comment: Why you didn't check for the max value in 'voteCounts' array, and return its index? Since I think this `int majority = (votes.length + 1) / 2;` may not satisfied, but we still have majority element. For example, in this array: `int[] array1 = {2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 1, 7};`, 3 is majority and it is not repeated 5 times. (your constraints are considered as well, vote range from 0 to 8)

Comment: Why didn't I?  Because that's not what the problem as stated in the question asks for!  The stated requirement is to find the **majority** value, and to throw an exception if there is no majority.

Comment: You mean 3 is not 'most common occurrence' number in this array? `{2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 1, 7}` Perhaps, this misunderstanding raise from difference between `'Majority element'` and `'most common occurrence element'` in an array. (Title says: 'most common occurrence element' and description says: "majority element'). Anyway, thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 2):

I just created such a beautiful and small solution with the new Java 8:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MostCommonObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(mostCommonObject(new Integer[] { -4, 1, -2, 3, 1, -2, 3, 1 }));
    }

    public static <T> T mostCommonObject(T[] array) {
        return mostCommonObject(Arrays.asList(array));
    }

    public static <T> T mostCommonObject(Collection<T> collection) {
        Map<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        collection.forEach(t -> map.compute(t, (k, i) -> i == null ? 1 : i + 1));
        return map.entrySet().stream().max((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.getValue(), e2.getValue())).get().getKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This one,

```
    Integer[] array=new Integer[]{10, 10, 10, 3, 10, 10, 6, 10, 10, 9, 10};

    List<Integer> demoList=new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));

    Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<Integer>(demoList);

    Map<Integer,Integer> myMap=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (Integer integer : set)
    {
        int count=Collections.frequency(demoList, integer);
        myMap.put(count, integer);            
    }

    int maxOccurance=myMap.get(Collections.max(myMap.keySet()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this: Convert your array to a list and sort it. Pick the first index, and call lastIndexOf(obj) on the value. Do this for each new value you encounter, calculate the range of the value and store the results of the biggest range in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is to count the occurrences of certain items in given set. In fact this was previously asked less than a day ago, you might want to look into this [very relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849831/java-is-there-an-object-like-a-set-that-can-contain-only-unique-string-values/).