# Find the 3 most frequent integers from an array

Tags: java

I would like to know how to find the 3 most frequent integers in an array. I read a file which the integers are inside, and i pass it to an array, this is what i have.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] num = readFiles("PATH FILE");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
}
public static int[] readFiles(String file){

    try{
        File fl = new File(file);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fl);
        int ctr = 0;
        while(scan.hasNextInt()){
            ctr++;
            scan.nextInt();
        }
        int[] array1 = new int[ctr];

        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(fl);

        for(int i = 0;i< array1.length;i++)
            array1[i] = scan1.nextInt();
        return array1;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Your question essentially is: `"here are some requirements and here is some code"` and that's about it. These sort of questions are **very** hard to answer well and usually get closed. Please tell us about the code, what does it do, what doesn't it do, and please try to ask a much more specific and answerable question and you'll likely get a decent and specific answer.

Comment: I convert a .txt to an array, inside the file .txt are integers, i need to find the 3 most frequent numbers

Answer (score 2):

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1852705/6496271

It can be modified to find the top 3 (all data is calculated and stored in m)